What does ように and おかげです mean in this context?
トキが生活しやすいようにみんなが頑張っているおかげです
ように means:
1.in order to (e.g. meet goal); so that; take care (so as)
2.hoping or wishing for something
3.appears; like
おかげです: means thanks to；because of
In order to Tokis can live comfortably, It's thanks to everyone's efforts?
How can you thanks somebody on something you intended to do or hasn't happened yet ?

For those who wish to check it, it appears this text comes from an NHK Easy article here: https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10014491831000/k10014491831000.html

"so that Toki can live comfortably" or "in order for Toki to live comfortably".

The full phrase トキが生活しやすいようにみんなが頑張っている modifies おかげ. So it means "It's thanks to everyone's efforts to help Toki live comfortably."
ように means "in order to" or "so that" Toki can live comfortably. You asked "How can you thanks somebody on something you intended to do or hasn't happened yet?" They are being thanked for their current efforts, not for something that hasn't happened yet.

Thanks you the reply.I think what I am confused of is that ように means working toward something (目的) in this context ? or where did you get the meaning of help out of the sentence.  おかげ means thanks to something, it results in something positive/negative. So i have 'Thanks to everyone's effort on working towards Toki live comfortably.'

Yes that's right

I've added some details that I hope better address your specific concerns.
